# Including QT packages

Tags: c++, qt

I have a directory in my home directory as qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.2.
This directory contains the basic QT packages and all but the problem is that when i compile a normal Qt file present in the home directory it shows error that the respective QT packages are not found.however,when i try to compile a normal c file by gcc and c++ file by g++ then it gives no error.
All i want is to know that how can i include those packages present in the directory.
My file which i am trying to compile is :-

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget window;

    window.resize(250, 150);
    window.setWindowTitle("Simple example");
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

ERRORS =

```
demo.cpp:1:24: error: QApplication: No such file or directory
demo.cpp:2:19: error: QWidget: No such file or directory
demo.cpp: In function âint main(int, char**)â:
demo.cpp:6: error: âQApplicationâ was not declared in this scope
demo.cpp:6: error: expected â;â before âappâ
demo.cpp:8: error: âQWidgetâ was not declared in this scope
demo.cpp:8: error: expected â;â before âwindowâ
demo.cpp:10: error: âwindowâ was not declared in this scope
demo.cpp:14: error: âappâ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the errors you get?

Comment: qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.2 is Qt _source_. You must build it to get qmake binary and libraries. It is probably much more convenient to install it through your package manager (on Linux) or to download the QtSDK (on Windows).

Comment: Go to this site: http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/installation.html and make sure you've done all of the steps correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should add this line to your .pro file:
`QT += core gui`

Comment: when i try to create .pro file by qmake -project command it says qmake command not found @hank

Comment: The default value for `QT` variable is already exactly `core gui`.

Comment: @user1465557 you need to add the $QTDIR/bin folder to your shell's PATH variable so that qmake will be in your command path.